# How to use pthread to write a C++ class like "boost::shared_mutex"

Tags: c++, boost, pthreads, posix

I want to write a class of pthread that have some functions with boost::shared_mutex.  I want to use `shared_lock<shared_mutex>`
I think that the constructor function is:

```
SharedMutex(){
  pthread_mutex_t sm;
  pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
  pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
  pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
  pthread_mutex_init(&sm,&attr);
}
```

Is it correct?

And I want to use 4 functions like boost:

```
void lock_shared();
void unlock_shared();
void lock();
void unlock();
```

But I don't know how to write these 4 functions, because `pthread_mutex` only have `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`

Comment: not an answer, but why not using std::thread? which uses pthread in cases of unix (I think).

Comment: C++ mutexes do not support all the options in pthread.

Comment: @doron as far as I know, in case of atomic operations, std::thread acts better.

Comment: Shared mutex aka read-write lock can't be implemented with one pthread mutex, you would need at least two. Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482648/reader-writer-lock-in-pthread?

Comment: @Oleg Bogdanov Do you know where have the complete cores?

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you looking for complete code? That would be wrong question for SO

Comment: Since you're on POSIX, why don't you just use a `sem_t`?